# How do I reference and render a metafield as an image on Shopify Collection Pages?

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid, shopify-liquid

I would really appreciate some advice on this issue:

We want a 4:1 collection header image on all of our collection pages for desktop.  1:1 is acceptable for mobile.  I have determined we will need 2 different images for each collection page (desktop-only and mobile-only).  Shopify collections do not let you upload or access more than 1 collection image.  Therefore, I have decided to use the collection image as the 4:1 desktop image and am relying on a metafield (datatype is a url string) for the mobile-only collection image.  I am struggling to reference the metafield correctly and get it to render as an image for mobile.

Original Image sizes:

4:1 - 2048px x 512px

1:1 - 1024px x 1024px

Here is the code in the section main-collection.liquid:

```
{% if header_image_enabled %}
  <div class="page-header page-header--with-background page-header--background-desktop-only image-overlay image-overlay--bg-{{ section.settings.overlay_style }} page-header--padded-{{ section.settings.heading_image_height }} rimage-wrapper">
    <div class="rimage-background lazyload fade-in"
      data-bgset="{% render 'bgset', image: collection.image %}"   
  data-sizes="auto"
      data-parent-fit="contain"></div>
  
    <div class="page-header-background-mobile-only image-overlay image-overlay--bg-{{ section.settings.overlay_style }} page-header--padded-{{ section.settings.heading_image_height }} rimage-wrapper">
    <div class="rimage-background lazyload fade-in"
      data-bgset="{% render 'bgset', collection.metafields.assets.image2 %}"   
  data-sizes="auto"
      data-parent-fit="cover"></div>
```

Here is the current code for snippet bgset.liquid:

```
    {%- if image != blank and image != collection.metafields.assets.image2 -%}
  {% if image.width > 180 %}{{ image | img_url: '180x' }} 180w {{ 180 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 360 %}{{ image | img_url: '360x' }} 360w {{ 360 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 540 %}{{ image | img_url: '540x' }} 540w {{ 540 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 720 %}{{ image | img_url: '720x' }} 720w {{ 720 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 900 %}{{ image | img_url: '900x' }} 900w {{ 900 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 1080 %}{{ image | img_url: '1080x' }} 1080w {{ 1080 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 1296 %}{{ image | img_url: '1296x' }} 1296w {{ 1296 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 1512 %}{{ image | img_url: '1512x' }} 1512w {{ 1512 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 1728 %}{{ image | img_url: '1728x' }} 1728w {{ 1728 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 1950 %}{{ image | img_url: '1950x' }} 1950w {{ 1950 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 2100 %}{{ image | img_url: '2100x' }} 2100w {{ 2100 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 2260 %}{{ image | img_url: '2260x' }} 2260w {{ 2260 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 2450 %}{{ image | img_url: '2450x' }} 2450w {{ 2450 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 2700 %}{{ image | img_url: '2700x' }} 2700w {{ 2700 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 3000 %}{{ image | img_url: '3000x' }} 3000w {{ 3000 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 3350 %}{{ image | img_url: '3350x' }} 3350w {{ 3350 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 3750 %}{{ image | img_url: '3750x' }} 3750w {{ 3750 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 4100 %}{{ image | img_url: '4100x' }} 4100w {{ 4100 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {{ image | img_url: 'master' }} {{ image.width }}w {{ image.height }}h
{%- endif -%}
{%- if image != blank and image == collection.metafields.assets.image2 -%}
    {% if image.width > 180 %}{{ image | img_url: '180x' }} 180w {{ 180 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 360 %}{{ image | img_url: '360x' }} 360w {{ 360 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 540 %}{{ image | img_url: '540x' }} 540w {{ 540 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 720 %}{{ image | img_url: '720x' }} 720w {{ 720 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 900 %}{{ image | img_url: '900x' }} 900w {{ 900 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 1080 %}{{ image | img_url: '1080x' }} 1080w {{ 1080 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 1296 %}{{ image | img_url: '1296x' }} 1296w {{ 1296 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 1512 %}{{ image | img_url: '1512x' }} 1512w {{ 1512 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 1728 %}{{ image | img_url: '1728x' }} 1728w {{ 1728 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 1950 %}{{ image | img_url: '1950x' }} 1950w {{ 1950 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 2100 %}{{ image | img_url: '2100x' }} 2100w {{ 2100 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 2260 %}{{ image | img_url: '2260x' }} 2260w {{ 2260 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 2450 %}{{ image | img_url: '2450x' }} 2450w {{ 2450 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 2700 %}{{ image | img_url: '2700x' }} 2700w {{ 2700 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 3000 %}{{ image | img_url: '3000x' }} 3000w {{ 3000 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 3350 %}{{ image | img_url: '3350x' }} 3350w {{ 3350 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {% if image.width > 3750 %}{{ image | img_url: '3750x' }} 3750w {{ 3750 | divided_by: image.aspect_ratio | round }}h,{% endif %}
  {{ image | img_url: 'medium' }} {{ image.width }}w {{ image.height }}h
{% endif %}
```

Again, collection.image is rendering in the Header for desktop, but collection.metafields.assets.image2 is not rendering as the Header image on mobile, which is what we want.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the metafield image to:

```
assign mob_image = collection.metafields.assets.image2 | image_url
```

and change the mobile reference line to:

```
data-bgset="{% render 'bgset', image: mob_image %}"
```